# Simple Divide and conquer proof

Tags: divide-and-conquer

Suppose a simple program is reading messages from a distributed cluster. 
The cluster has 3 partitions, and the program has three readers that are assigned one partition each *(The setup will always be x partitions connected to x readers, where x can be 3, 4, etc... Each reader handles a specific partition alone. Hence, it only makes sense to have the exactly same number of readers and partitions)*. The readers work in parallel. 
When the cluster receives a messages it puts that message into the partition that is less crowded with messages.

Suppose that all the 3 partitions have the same load of data.

If the total load of data is n messages *(in all the partitions)*, then, because we have 3 readers it is possible to divide the reading process in n/3 parts. 
This intuitively states that: **The capacity of reading increases linearly with the number of added partitions and readers.**

The more readers and partitions we have, the faster it will be. It is clear for me, and this is quite simple, but I am not able to find a mathematical proof for this.

What would be the simplest mathematical proof for this scenario?

Comment: You will have to formulate your problem more formally before you can offer a mathematical proof. We can only mathematically prove mathematical statements.

Comment: I tried to reformulate it with an intuitive statement. Thank you for your comment.